# Finding Minimum Cost of a M*M land

Tags: python

A certain builder wants to build a building on a square land with a length and width of m. The builder divides the land into m*m grids, and the development cost of each grid is stored in the corresponding position of a matrix as an integer. Now we need to help builders figure out which type of base to use and where to build it to minimize development costs. Builders are expected to choose one of the following four base styles;

[image: The Four Base Styles]

Input:
Read an N*N matrix data where 2 <= N <=100. The first line of the test case contains the value of N. The next N rows are the values of the development cost matrix, and the elements in each row are separated by blanks.

And i need to output the value of the minimum development cost.

```
def find_min_development_cost(N, matrix):
    dp = [[0] * N for _ in range(N)]
    
    dp[0][0] = matrix[0][0]
    for i in range(1, N):
        dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + matrix[i][0]
        dp[0][i] = dp[0][i-1] + matrix[0][i]
    
    for i in range(1, N):
        for j in range(1, N):
            dp[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1])
    
    return dp[N-1][N-1]

N = 4
matrix = [
    [2, 1, 5, 2],
    [4, 1, 4, 2],
    [2, 2, 4, 1],
    [4, 2, 6, 4]
]

min_development_cost = find_min_development_cost(N, matrix)

print(min_development_cost)
```

The output given the above `n` and `matrix` values should be `7`, but i keep on getting an output of `15`. Can someone help me what is the problem over here?

Comment: Start with some basic debugging: write out the steps (on paper) that need to happen in order for the output to end up being `7`, and then walk through your code to see at what point "what should be happening at this step" isn't actually what's happening at that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve this problem using convolution (I don't recommend actually using my code, but I wrote an unoptimized, vanilla python version for your understanding. You can use numpy to do much more efficient convolutions).

```
matrix = [
    [2, 1, 5, 2],
    [4, 1, 4, 2],
    [2, 2, 4, 1],
    [4, 2, 6, 4]
]

matrix_rows = len(matrix)
matrix_cols = len(matrix[0])

# imagine a base as binary image of 1s and 0s, this gives you:
base_styles = [
    [[1,1,1],[0,1,0]], # pointing down v
    [[1,0],[1,1],[1,0]], # pointing right >
    [[0,1],[1,1],[0,1]], # pointing left <
    [[0,1,0],[1,1,1]], # pointing up ^
]

# then you can use convolution (multiply the image of the base, with the 
# currently selected position of the matrix and sum the result) to find the cost

lowest_cost = None
optimal_layout = None
optimal_position = None

for style_index in range(len(base_styles)):
    style = base_styles[style_index]
    height = len(style)
    width = len(style[0])
    for j in range(matrix_rows-height+1): # selected Y position in matrix
        for i in range(matrix_cols-width+1): # selected X position in matrix
            cost = 0
            for y in range(height):
                for x in range(width):
                    cost += style[y][x]*matrix[y+j][x+i]
            if lowest_cost == None or cost < lowest_cost:
                lowest_cost = cost
                optimal_layout = style_index
                optimal_position = (j,i)
                
print((lowest_cost,optimal_layout,optimal_position))
# output is: (7, 2, (1, 0))
# meaning the optimal build is:
# [_, _, _, _]
# [_, #, _, _]
# [#, #, _, _]
# [_, #, _, _]
# and it costs 7 units to build
```

Comment: Sorry there was a small mistake where I forgot to check all base styles after debugging, the code is fixed now.